# How to Rediscover members of a TCP group using TCPPING or any other Discovery protocols

Tags: jgroups

How can I rediscover members of a group by its cluster-name? I am using JGroups 2.7.0
In a particular situation, members are isolated and are not connected (network failure) and when the network is back up, I would like to know all other members so they are in the same group again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found solution to this. When the connection is established, I sent FIND_INITIAL_MEMBERS event up in the stack using MERGE2 protocol of the stack and that did merge all the isolated members together.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the connection to the network is established, trigger FIND_INITIAL_MEMBERS event up in the stack using MERGE2 protocol of the stack and that will merge all the isolated members together.